Strange behaviour of the gain register on image sensor OV7251 (with graphs!)
I am working with the OV7251 image sensor from Omnivision (sorry, the datasheet is not public, so I can't link to it). According to the datasheet, the gain and exposure can be set. The datasheet explains how the 8-bit gain register (0x350B) works:

This does seem pretty weird, and theoretically gives a response that looks like this:

I decided to test this and actually measure the image brightness for every register value, and the real response looks like this:

It looks quite unlike the theoretical response, but does have four main regions of 16, 32, 64 and 128 values. Interestingly, there's a subtle non-straightness or grouping visible in each sections. The groups are 1, 2 4 and 8 values in size.
Questions:

Am I completely misunderstanding the datasheet, and how the gain register works?
If the datasheet is wrong, what actually is the function that connects register value to gain?
Is there some significance to the slight grouping visible in the response?


Is this the datasheet?

@SpehroPefhany - It is. But I don't want to get in their naughty books.


Yes. Or not taking something else into account, like other settings that affect the gain. Such as the register that sets if you want to use linear or logarithmic gain. You also did not provide a formula you used so we can't verify if it matches what you posted. It is likely be incorrect. Based on the formula, no value should be 0, and your graph has 16 zeroes.

The other register bits that affect the mode of gain. Or you have an old datasheet, or a datasheet that does not match your version of the sensor module revision. You must be sure which camera silicon/firmware your module has and how to use it's registers correctly. Different sensor revisions must use different settings.

It sure looks like there is. Looks like logarithmic function. 0..15 are flat zero, 16..31 is first range, 32..63 second range, 64..127 third range, and 128..255 fourth range.


But since you are asking about stuff in non-free data sheet, you should ask the vendor, they know what is going on inside the chip. I am just guessing here.

I would love to ask the vendor, but they're extremely non-forthcoming about these kinds of questions.
